# Downloading files from Servlets - Chrome warning + how to redirect user after download?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a simple table with downlod file links..

Everything seems to work fine, when I click download, the file is found on the harddrive and served to the user.

My problem is, when I inspect chrome I see:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:8080/fus-app/myUploadedFiles".
```

Why would it say that?

The relevant code I have is:

```
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileNameOnSystem + "\"");
```

Also a bonus question:

After the file is downloaded, the user still sees the page with the table, but I want to redirect to a different page. How can I do that?

```
 response.sendRiderect()
```

does not seem to work.

Edit: This is how I provide download link to the user:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= request.getServletContext().getContextPath() +"/myUploadedFiles" %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileNameOnSystem" value="<%= rset.getString("fileNameOnSystem") %>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />Download File </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the HTML5 download attribute in your download link:

```
<a href='http://example.com/archive.zip' download>Export</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

As for the redirect, not good news here [Is it possible to forward or redirect from a servlet filter after the response has been committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407000/is-it-possible-to-forward-or-redirect-from-a-servlet-filter-after-the-response-h/3407316#3407316) ...

> The "committed" status of an HttpServletResponse is really a way of
>   saying whether the response headers have been written to the
>   underlying socket. A "committed" response has had (at least) the first
>   line written. Since the first line of the response contains the status
>   code, it follows that you cannot change the status code of a committed
>   response ... and that means it is too late to change the status to 3xx
>   to do a redirect. Similarly, you cannot do a local forward because
>   you've already started sending the response.

So you won't be able to do anything more with the response after you've sent the file (which is a committed response).  However, you could forward them onto another page first, and then have that display a message and eventually trigger the download.

Found this example:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://server.com/file.zip">  
</head>  
<body>  
Thank you for downloading file.zip!  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my question. Actually the file is somewhere in the drive so I must provide the file from the servlet, I can not have a direct link to the file.

Comment: File name on system is something like: test1234.pdf, and I know in which directory it is ( like C:\appuser\test1234.pdf ) so I can provide the file. So I can only provide some sort of parameter to the servlet, then I give away the file.

Comment: You should be able to just provide the URL that the servlet handles.  The client doesn't know whether or not it's an actual file or you're just generating random bits.  So if your servlet handles woogie.com/somefile, you can still put:  `<a href='http://woogie.com/myfile' download>Export</a>` on your web page.